# Which sentence is correct ? 我 对 欧洲 历史 很 熟悉 or 我 很 熟悉 欧洲 历史

Tags: grammar

我 对 欧洲 历史 很 熟悉  or   我 很 熟悉  欧洲 历史

Which one is correct? Can I use both forms of the sentence or not? I mean with or without prepositions.

Comment: Both expressions are correct. In an oral conversation, they are both unnatural. But they are flawless in grammar. In conversations, it's more of "对...有所了解" (I got some acquintance with...)

Answer (score 6):

They are quite similar. However, most of the time, the object immediately after the verb would be considered the emphasized part of the sentence. So, 我对欧洲历史很熟悉 may appear more in the context of discussing history of various places, whereas 我很熟悉欧洲历史 may appear more in the context of discussing the knowledge of European history. But anyway, they are nearly the same, and are interchangeable in most of the time.

Comment: Well explained. One is familiar with a particular subject among many, and the other is familiar with the subject in general.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

我 对 欧洲 历史 **很 熟悉** - I **know quite well** as to European history.

or 我 **很 熟悉** 欧洲 历史 - I am **quite familiar with** European history.

No difference, but the latter sounds more natural.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the first one is more used when talking to someone, when writing, the second one should be better.

But those two sentences describe the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Both  are correct, but the meaning are a little different.

"我对欧洲历史很熟悉", places more emphasis on the object, "European history." This sentence could be used in a conversation with the topic of European history

"我很熟悉欧洲历史," places more emphasis on the subject, "I." This sentence could be used  in a conversation with the topic of hobbies, knowledge, skills.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. They can be used interchangeably because they mean the same.  Say whichever you want. No specific rules or contexts can only be applied to the former, not the latter, vice versa. This is the answer from a native Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

No difference!

If you must say something is different between these two expressions, the first one sounds like a student wanting to know how to translate this sentence to Chinese.